# How to close a pop up window by clicking the close button?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, popup

This is my div in the aspx page:

```
<div id="pop-up">

    <button id="btnClose">Close</button>
        <div id="mopopuptitle">
        </div>
        <table id="popuptable" cellspacing="15">
        </table>
    </div>
```

This is my js code:

```
$('td#' + parentElement).find('span.download_active').next().hover(function (e) {
                topPos = e.pageY - ($('div#pop-up').height()) - 35;
                leftPos = e.pageX - ($('div#pop-up').width()) - 30;
                if (leftPos < 0) { leftPos = 10; }
                GetAssociatedPeopleList(json_row.value.task_id);
                $('div#pop-up').show().css('top', topPos).css('left', leftPos).appendTo('body');
                $('#mopopuptitle').html('People who have taken up this Request');
                $('#btnClose').button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-closethick" }, text: false })
            .css({ width: '30px', height: '20px', position: 'absolute', right: -'25px', top: '-25px' })
            .click($(this).close());
            }, function() {


            });
```

The above code has some business logic. Dont bother about that.. All i need is when i click the close button the pop up has to be closed..

I have tried these lines..

```
$('div#pop-up').show().css('top', topPos).css('left', leftPos).appendTo('body');
                $('#mopopuptitle').html('People who have taken up this Request');
                $('#btnClose').button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-closethick" }, text: false })
            .css({ width: '30px', height: '20px', position: 'absolute', right: -'25px', top: '-25px' })
            .click($(this).close());
```

I couldn achieve by trying this code.. What should i change?? Is there any alternative for this?? Please help me out..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code on "OnClientClick" event of your close button

```
$find('yourpopId').hide();
```

Comment: I dont want the pop up to hide automatically.. I want it to be closed only if the user clicks the close button

Comment: @Xavier Its say to you, onClientClick on the close button.

Comment: yes @Xavier write this code on  "OnClientClick" event of your close button .Like : function Close() { $find('yourpopId').hide();
 return false; } . and call this function on close button event like: OnClientClick = "return Close();"

Comment: @TarunTak
That works fine.. Thank u..
Can u help me to achieve this by using an icon instead of asp button..

Comment: @Xavier you you can use imagebutton instead of Normal button,and set image in background of that image button

Comment: @TarunTak
Thanks got that ..:-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code as well.

**Jquery:**

```
$('div#pop-up').dialog({ 
      buttons: [{ text: "Close" , click: function () {
    $(this).dialog("close"); }
                }]
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can control it from code behind:

The Page.asp:

```
<div id="pop-up" runat="server">
   <button id="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" />
    ...
</div>
```

The Page.asp.vb:

```
Private Sub btnClose_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
  pop-up.visible = False
End Sub
```